# Strange comb spectrum found during EMI precompliance

Tags: emc, spectrum, intermodulation-products

During near field testing I encountered this *thing* I've never seen neither on the wild nor on the book.  The board has an STM32F107 with an 8MHz crystal and *no ferrites or choke whatsoever* (I'm already crying.) The only other oscillating thing I could think of is the 24V to 5V switching regulator at about 40kHz. From what they tell me the 8MHz is multiplied with the STM32 PLL to obtain the main 72MHz clock.

With a magnetic field probe on a cable bundle from that board I see substantially a spectrum comb from about 4MHz to about 36MHz, spaced at about 105kHz (see image.)

[image: Spectrum]

As you can see it's quite regular and, by itself, it's not an issue (the 32-36MHz overtones however are *horrible* but that's another story, maybe the APB clock leaks, too.) What kind of phenomena could cause that? The most similar thing I could think of would be intermodulation but it would be so wide and regular in amplitude.

SIMPLE AND REALLY STUPID THEORY: from signal theory a Dirac comb signal gives a Dirac comb spectrum.

So what if that's simply a 105kHz really short pulse that expand up to the about 6-36MHz? That could be somehow the switching regulator with really low load (since it's so old it has no pulse skipping or other modern power saving techniques). Tomorrow I'll try to load it, if the pulse widens the upper harmonics should go down.

Comment: What is the MCU actually doing?

Comment: Is there maybe an I²C bus active somewhere? (maybe even active, but not terminated by actual devices / pullups in this prototype?)

Comment: What signal or power lines are in that cable bundle? Where is the 24V input voltage coming from? Another switch-mode power supply?

Comment: The cables are mostly sensor switches and similar but I believe it's all generated inside the board and radiated outside, even detaching everything except the supply leaves the field 'above' the board. External supply is from a commercial Omron power supply. There is indeed an I2C working but even with all that I don't get how a whole comb would be generated. I'll try to keep the MPU in reset to see what changes!

Comment: If holding the MPU in reset eliminates it, you might have a software cycle that, for instance, polls a sensor every ~10us.

Answer (score 5):

Let's do some math that explains what it could be, but it might be something else too.

So you have a 40 kHz switch mode buck converter, which has a period of 25 us.

The buck converter steps 24V down to 5V, which means it has 20.8% duty cycle, meaning it will be switched on for 5.2 us and switched off for 19.8 us.

Now those 5.2 us pulses have two edges 5.2 us apart so they create 50.5 kHz frequency content. As edges create odd harmonics, the odd harmonics are 101 kHz apart.

Another way to look at it is that the off pulses are 19.8 us long space between two edges, which makes 25.3 kHz frequency content. There is 101 kHz between that and 5th harmonic, and 101 kHz again from 5th to 9th harmonic.

So if I'd have to make an enlightened guess, such low frequencies that explain the periodic frequency spikes, it must be the switch mode power supply based on that the given information explains it.

It might be the components, wiring between them, or otherwise the PCB layout.

Test by adjusting the input supply voltage which changes the regulator duty cycle. At 10V you should get 50% duty, so you should have square wave which means all edges are equally spaced and you only get one base frequency and odd harmonics, but the regulator can run at different frequency whem there is 10V on input.

Just to be sure you could stop the MCU from running, but the regulator may go into pulse skipping mode on light loads.

Comment: Great insight, I developed a theory with that!

Answer (score 2):

I see this behavior a lot when I'm troubleshooting switching power controllers. This behavior is known as **diode emulation**, which behaves as a "safe mode" for switching power supplies.

During startup, if the output capacitor already has some voltage stored (pre-bias), current might try to flow back from the capacitor to the source. This "reverse current" can cause unwanted spikes (negative transients) on the output voltage. To prevent these spikes, the controller can turn off the low-side switch (sync-FET) at just the right moment.

This way of controlling the sync-FET is called diode emulation.  By turning it off strategically, the controller makes the switch act like a diode, which only allows current to flow in one direction. This prevents the reverse current and keeps the output voltage stable.

Comment: so a sensible testing strategy would be to add a load resistor to the SMPS output and check whether that alleviates the issue?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Adding a load resistor can help provide a current sink to help reduce the chance of reverse current, yes. You could also test various pre-bias voltages at startup if you want to study various SMPS behaviors.

Comment: I don't think that would be the case. The regulator is an ancient MC330xx (with a BJT switch!) so no synch rectifier. The load however is indeed low so as  far as I know it could be even out of stability (old switchers had this problem IIRC). Another useful attempt, I'll try to load the 5V rail to see what changes